# How to set std::array size via parameter pack arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, stdarray

I have an N-dimensional Matrix class that has a constructor with a parameter pack. Is it possible to set the size of the `std::array` member variable depending on the values in the parameter pack? As far as I understand the values in the parameter pack should be known at compile time.

```
template<size_t N>
class Matrix {
public:
    template<typename... Exts>
    Matrix(Exts... exts) : dimSizes{exts...} { }

private:
    std::array<size_t, N> dimSizes;
    std::array<float, N> data;
    // e.g something like this: std::array<float, dimSizes[0]> data;
};

int main(void) {
    Matrix<3> mat(2, 3, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't you use the initialisation list of the constructor?

Comment: Sort of in c++17, no (mostly) before.  Unless I warp your question.

Comment: You can't have `sizeof(Matrx<3>)` magically vary depending on how an instance was constructed.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't think so. I have to specify the size of the `std::array` via a template argument. So I have to specify the size as soon as I declare it.

Comment: @SPA what stops you from using `std::vector<float>(dimSizes[0])` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki main reason is that `std::array` should be more efficient + I want to prevent that `Matrix::data` can change in size.

Comment: @SPA then you will probably have to use `Matrix<3, 2> mat(3, 2);` instead

Comment: @SPA - If the `vector` is a private member, only your class or a `friend` will be able to change it.   Both cases should be under your control when defining the class.   And, unless you've measured or memory is VERY tight on your target system, your claim of "efficiency" is spurious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to set the size of the `std::array` member variable depending on the values in the parameter pack?
>
> // e.g something like this: `std::array<float, dimSizes[0]> data;`

No, as far I know is impossible exactly as you want.

Because, this way, different instances of the same class would contain members with same name but different types. Strictly forbidden in a strongly typed language as C++.

If you want a `std::array` with different size, you have to differentiate the types; so the dimension for the second `std::array` has to be a template parameter.

Obviously you can substitute the `std::array` with a container that doesn't depend from the size; as suggested by Piotr Skotnicki a possible solution is `std::vector`

Comment: _"Because, this way, different instances of the same class would contain members with same name but different types."_ Good argument. I completly missed that.